# Set background color based on a CSS class name

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, background-color

I have these different div elements with classes such as `red` or `green`.

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="color_box red"></div>
    <div class="color_box orange"></div>
    <div class="color_box yellow"></div>
    <div class="color_box green"></div>
    <div class="color_box blue"></div>
    <div class="color_box purple"></div>
    <div class="color_box black"></div>
    <div class="color_box white"></div>
</div>
```

I want to set the background color of the div element to its class name. So if the class name is `red`, I would want the div background to be red. I'm not sure if I need to add javascript or something else. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061156/how-to-set-text-color-depends-on-element-class-name-in-css3) and it was not what I wanted at all.

*Thank you in advance!*

Comment: Will `class` only have those two classes (`color_box` and the color)?

Comment: How should this be any different than using `style="background-color: red"` as an attribute?

Comment: @OskarGrosser yes

Comment: @EmielZuurbier because with `style="background-color: red"`, I would have to go through every color that I wanted. (`. . . background-color: red`
`. . . background-color: blue`
etc.) Does that makes sense?

Comment: Hey @Kian now that I see the accepted answer it makes sense what you want, but my suggestion is to be more clear and concise about what you're looking for - people are kinda sensitive on here lol :)

Comment: @Kian So now you will write `data-backgroundcolor="red" . . . data-backgroundcolor="yellow"` instead of `style="background-color: red"` lolll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that is dynamic and does not depend on class names is the use of a custom [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Take a look at the following solution:

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <div data-backgroundcolor="red" class="color_box">BOX</div>
    <div data-backgroundcolor="orange" class="color_box">BOX</div>
    <div data-backgroundcolor="yellow" class="color_box">BOX</div>
    <div data-backgroundcolor="green" class="color_box">BOX</div>
    <div data-backgroundcolor="blue" class="color_box">BOX</div>
    <div data-backgroundcolor="purple" class="color_box">BOX</div>
    <div data-backgroundcolor="black" class="color_box">BOX</div>
    <div data-backgroundcolor="white" class="color_box">BOX</div>
</div>

<script>
    const colorboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.color_box');
    colorboxes.forEach(el => {
        el.style.backgroundColor = el.dataset.backgroundcolor
    })
</script>
```

Comment: This works just as well! Thank you!
I'm just curious how this line of code works `el.style.backgroundColor = el.dataset.backgroundcolor`. Is it getting the tag(?) attached to an HTML element and then setting the background color to what's in the quotation marks?

Comment: Exactly. You can access any data attribute, which is any attribute prefixed by `data-`, using `element.dataset.your_custom_name`. You can read more about how data attributes work in the link I added.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to approach this without JavaScript if you're using the SASS pre-processor would be to use an [@each](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) rule.

```
$colors: red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, black, white;

@each $color in $colors {
    .bg-color-#{$color} {
        background-color: $color;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/djnetherton/pen/xxgBYyE?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

The solution below will get the color name in the class and set it to background color.

**REMEMBER** This specific solution will only works if the color class is the second class in the list.

`var background = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1];` will give second class name in class names list.

For example:

`$(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0]` is `color_box`

and

`$(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1]` is `red`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".color_box").each(function(){
     var background = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
     $(this).css("background-color",background);
   });
});
```

```css
.color_box {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="color_box red"></div>
    <div class="color_box orange"></div>
    <div class="color_box yellow"></div>
    <div class="color_box green"></div>
    <div class="color_box blue"></div>
    <div class="color_box purple"></div>
    <div class="color_box black"></div>
    <div class="color_box white"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! With this line of code, `var background = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1];`, is the `[1]` at the end saying to look at the second class?

Comment: Yes `$(this).attr("class").split(" ")` will give you an array of class names for that element for example `["color_box","red"]`. Then `$(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0]` is `color_box` and `$(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1]` is `red`

Comment: I recommand to not use JQuery if you not alredy have jquery on your app. You can easly create the same function using native javascript.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all `.color_box`-elements
2. For-each:

   1. Find class-name, that is not `color_box`
   2. Set background-color to found class-name

No need for jQuery or any other library! It's all native JavaScript!

```js
const colorboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.color_box');

for (let cb of colorboxes) {
  cb.style.backgroundColor = Object.values(cb.classList).find(e => e != 'color_box');
}
```

```css
div.color_box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="color_box red"></div>
  <div class="color_box orange"></div>
  <div class="color_box yellow"></div>
  <div class="color_box green"></div>
  <div class="color_box blue"></div>
  <div class="color_box purple"></div>
  <div class="color_box black"></div>
  <div class="color_box white"></div>
</div>
```